# Angular smart-table fail to render collection based on objects list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

I converted my Items Array into an indexed object using underscorejs:

```
  $scope.items = _.indexBy($scope.items, 'id');
```

And now my items looks like this:

```
  $scope.items = {
    "1": {
        id: 1,
      name: "Tizio"
    },
    "2": {
        id: 2,
      name: "Caio"
    },
    "3": {
        id: 3,
      name: "Sempronio"
    },
  };
```

It is exactly what I need.

Now I need to show my items in a Table and I would like to use a plugin that help me to sort, paginate, filter my data easily, so I started to use `angular-smart-table`. A famous and common one...

I followed the documentation and the final HTML looks like this:

```
<table st-safe-src="items" st-table="rowItems">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng:repeat="item in rowItems track by item.id">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't show my data. I tried to remove smart table and it work fine in a common table.

How can I let it work? What I'm doing wrong? If smart table doesn't support list of Objects, do you know a better plugin that should better fit my needs?

[Here a JsFiddle about it](https://jsfiddle.net/qfpyu1kL/).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure what you were trying to do with the `[].concat(OBJECT)`, so I changed the way of converting from Object to array using `Object.keys` and `map`.

You can check the updated jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qfpyu1kL/2/

```
  // Initial values converted to array
  $scope.rowItems = Object.keys($scope.items).map(function(key) {
    return $scope.items[key];
  });

  $timeout(function () {
    // Add new values
    $scope.rowItems.push({ id: 4, name: 'OTHER1' });
    $scope.rowItems.push({ id: 5, name: 'OTHER2' });
  }, 1000);
```

I've seen that you were using stSafeSrc, which meant you were expecting asynchronous data, thats why I added the $timeout.

I also updated the HTML to set `rowItems` in `st-safe-src`attribute and `st-table` to `displayedCollection`.

Comment: Well, basically you converted back the indexed list to be an Array... Fair enough. Thanks for the answer and solution

Comment: Hello again, after reviewing better the code I found that after a few seconds it generate an infinite digest loop. Specially since I added `rowItems` to `st-safe-src`...

Comment: Updated jsfiddle, just rename `st-table` attribute and use this new name in the `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Thanks, I sorted it out!